# i have an multidimensional array given below

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

i have an array like this

```
$x = array("1" =>array("PHP","code"), "foo" =>array("bar", 5 ,11));

for($i=1;$i<count($x);$i++)
{
    foreach($x[$i] as $key=>$value){
        echo $key.$value;
    }
echo "<br>";
}
```

and i want output like this:

`1.php
1.code
foo.bar
foo.5
foo.11`

how could i get this out put.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
foreach ($x AS $key => $val) {
  foreach ($val AS $sub) {
    echo $key . '.' . $sub . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each array, like so;

```
<?php

$x = array("1" =>array("PHP","code"),  
           "foo" =>array("bar", 5 ,11)
          );

foreach($x as $key => $a) {
   foreach($a as $c) {
     echo $key . "." . $c . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

https://eval.in/198869

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$x = array("1" =>array("PHP","code"), "foo" =>array("bar", 5 ,11));

foreach($x as $m=>$n){
    foreach($n as $y=>$x){

       $arrayList[]= $m.".".strtolower($x);
     }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayList);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the line break `<br>` inside the inner loop, like this:

```
$x = array( "1" => array("PHP","code"), "foo" => array("bar", 5 ,11));

foreach($x as $key=>$val){

     foreach($val as $value){
         echo $key.".".$value."<br>";
     }

}
```